# Core Data throws NSInternalInconsistencyException "The context is still dirty after 100 attempts."

Tags: macos, cocoa, exception, core-data

I struggle finding cause of the following exception. It occurs from time to time with no clear pattern I can repeat to reproduce problem.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: 'Failed to process pending changes before save. 
The context is still dirty after 100 attempts. 
Typically this recursive dirtying is caused by a bad validation method, 
-willSave, or notification handler.'
```

The application stores and process tracking data and deals with only one entity:

```
@interface CSTrackingEntry : NSManagedObject
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * data;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * dateRecorded;
@end
```

CSTracking entries are read, created and deleted in batches. Few up to dozen in a batch, once every couple of minutes. There is no notification handlers registered.

**UPDATE: Stack captured**

```
2012-02-03 10:26:11.121 BatteryNurse[17162:1803] An uncaught exception was raised
2012-02-03 10:26:11.121 BatteryNurse[17162:1803] Failed to process pending changes 
before save.  The context is still dirty after 100 attempts.  Typically this recursive 
dirtying is caused by a bad validation method, -willSave, or notification handler.
2012-02-03 10:26:11.264 BatteryNurse[17162:1803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to process pending changes 
before save.  The context is still dirty after 100 attempts.  Typically this recursive 
dirtying is caused by a bad validation method, -willSave, or notification handler.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8183f784 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff89306f03 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreData                            0x00007fff8543a654 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalChangeProcessing) _prepareForPushChanges:] + 244
3   CoreData                            0x00007fff8543a0af -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 207
4   BatteryNurse                        0x0000000100075ee6 __40-[CSTrackingEntry(Methods) deleteObject]_block_invoke_0 + 102
5   BatteryNurse                        0x000000010007514f __42-[CSCoreDataKernel(CoreData) executeSync:]_block_invoke_0 + 79
6   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff869bcfbb dispatch_barrier_sync_f + 79
7   BatteryNurse                        0x00000001000750ee -[CSCoreDataKernel(CoreData) executeSync:] + 110
8   BatteryNurse                        0x0000000100075e6f -[CSTrackingEntry(Methods) deleteObject] + 175
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff817ff123 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 499
10  BatteryNurse                        0x000000010003a13f -[CSTracker(PrivateMethods) processAndSendBundlesToServer] + 383
11  BatteryNurse                        0x00000001000393a4 __23-[CSTracker flushAsync]_block_invoke_0 + 420
12  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff869c3d64 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
13  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff869a28d2 _dispatch_queue_drain + 251
14  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff869a2734 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 57
15  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff869a22de _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
16  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff869a1c08 _pthread_wqthread + 353
17  libSystem.B.dylib                   0x00007fff869a1aa5 start_wqthread + 13
```

Answer (score 12):

You are modifying the object while it's being saved. If you're observing `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` (which will be posted as part of the save, but before the actual saving happens), and you change objects are a result of that notification, you'll create a loop:

When you call `-save:` CoreData first calls `-processPendingChanges:` (if there are changes). As part of that CoreData sends out an `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` notification. If additional objects changed while the notification was being processed, it calls `-processPendingChanges:` again, sends out the notification again, etc. Once there are no pending changes, CoreData persists the objects to the store. If pending changes keep appearing CoreData will eventually give up and print

```
The context is still dirty after 100 attempts.
```

That's the gist of it.